# java spring problem : project can not run on tomcat server even though edited the server.xml file?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I am newbie with java spring and here is my problem.

I created a simple project named DiamonShop and tried to run it by tomcat 9.0.62.

But it show me this error

[image: my error]

I think that the error is because of the file server.xml, because I have 2 projects named DemoSpringMVC and DiamonShop, in the file server.xml, I found that there is this line

```
<Context docBase="DemoSpringMVC" path="/DemoSpringMVC" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:DemoSpringMVC"/>
  <Context docBase="DiamonShop" path="/DiamonShop" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:DiamonShop"/></Host>
```

And the link `http://localhost:8888/DemoSpringMVC/` worked perfectly
When I changed the line above into this

```
<Context docBase="DiamonShop" path="/DiamonShop" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:DiamonShop"/></Host>
```

The link `http://localhost:8888/DemoSpringMVC/` did not work, so I thought that maybe the link `http://localhost:8888/DiamonShop/` must work ? But it did not.

I also tried tomcat 8.5 and tomcat 10, but it showed the same error.

Here is my code (DemoSpringMVC and DiamonShop), for reference, if you need.

```
https://github.com/nguyencuc2586/Spring3.3
https://github.com/nguyencuc2586/DIamonShop4.1
```

Here is my webapp directory

[image: webapp directory]

Here is my server.xml file

```
https://github.com/nguyencuc2586/DiamonShop4.1Serverfile
```

Here is my webapp at my apache-tomcat

```
https://github.com/nguyencuc2586/DiamonShop4.1apache-tomcat-9.0.62-webapps
```

Could you please give me some advices for this problem ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please share ls output of webapps directory? Also would it be possible for you to share full server.xml file?

Comment: Btw: It is NOT recommended to place <Context> elements directly in the server.xml file.

Comment: @vish213 : thanks for your comment, I have been update all as you need

Comment: Sorry I should I have clarified, I meant webapps directory of tomcat. You'll find it in apache-tomcat-8.5.x directory.

Comment: @vish213 : thanks, I have been update the webapps folder as you need, you can download it and give me some advices ?

Comment: Your webapps folder doesn't have the application at all. The folder you're referring in docBase needs to be present in this directory. You can refer to https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/deployer-howto.html

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the docBase="DemoSpringMVC" you're referring to doesn't exist in webapp directory, because the war/jar file you might have built contains "SNAPSHOT" like strings.